# Validating email using js

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

I trying to create this form that only allows people to submit an email that is using a @msu.edu email. I have the alert that is coming up when it's not a msu.edu email, but when I use an email like test@msu.edu its not submitting the form.

```
function checkMail() {
    var email = document.validation.email.value.toLowerCase();
    var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@msu.edu/i;
    var result = filter.test(email);
    alert('Valid email found: ' + result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `.` there.

Correct code:

```
function checkMail() {
    var email = document.validation.email.value.toLowerCase();
    var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@msu\.edu/i;
    //                                       ^-- escape this dot
    var result = filter.test(email);
    alert('Valid email found: ' + result);
    return result;
}
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fJ4iW8)

Comment: I dont get what you are saying because its still not working. If it passes the test then it should go on to my php page that i have created which sends it to my email

Comment: What Gaurang is saying is that you were allowing `@msukedu`, `@msupedu`, etc. as valid — which we assume isn't.

Comment: @user3240208 I created a test script and [it works in there](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/S63sT/1/)

Comment: After you enter the right email. The pop up box should not come up and the php page should load next

Comment: So, if you don't want the popup to appear if the user entered right email, you can wrap it in `if` like `if (result === true) postPHPrequest();  else alert("Invalid email entered");`

Comment: how do you disable the popup box if the email is right?

Answer (score 1):

Format in just like this... `var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@msu\.edu/i;` as per Gaurang said. It works.

Answer (score 0):

why not try this

```
bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
    try {
        var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
        return true;
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will do it**

put this function onclick event of button and change getelementById's Id with your TextBox Id and this will give you alert "msu.edu"

```
     function checkMail() 
      {
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value.toLowerCase();
        var regex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\                  [[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/; ;
      if (regex.test(email)) 
        {
          var temp = email.substring(email.lastIndexOf("@")+1);
          if (temp != "msu.edu") 
          {
              alert("Enter correct email");
          }

      }

  }
```